# Ruby on Rails:-Rails s and Rails Server commands all create new projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, xubuntu

I am experiencing some weird rails behaviour:

When I do the following commands

```
rails new blog

rails s

rails server
```

The result for each is a new project, that is 3 folders names new, s, server, all with a new rails project in them

...why is this happening?? I have a feeling it may have to do with the versions I am using, I used rvm to update from 1.87 to 2.0 for Ruby and I just installed rails 2.3.14

I am using xubuntu which also just switched from Unity.

Comment: any reason why you are using `rails 2.3.14`, include the output of `which rails` in your question, my guess is `rails` is a alias to `rails new`

Comment: Yeah I just realized I should have rails 4

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a Rails 3.x command in a Rails 2.3 application. For Pre 3.0 applications you have to use the server script mentioned below.

From within your application directory run:

```
./script/server
```